# Right way to use RFECV and Permutation Importance - Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, feature-selection, eli5

There is a proposal to implement this in `Sklearn` [#15075](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15075), but in the meantime, `eli5` is suggested as a solution. However, I'm not sure if I'm using it the right way. This is my code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import eli5
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
perm = eli5.sklearn.PermutationImportance(estimator,  scoring='r2', n_iter=10, random_state=42, cv=3)
selector = RFECV(perm, step=1, min_features_to_select=1, scoring='r2', cv=3)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
selector.ranking_
```

There are a few issues:

1. I am not sure if I am using cross-validation the right way. `PermutationImportance` is using `cv` to validate importance on the validation set, or cross-validation should be only with `RFECV`? (in the example, I used `cv=3` in both cases, but not sure if that's the right thing to do)
2. If I run `eli5.show_weights(perm)`, I'll get: `AttributeError: 'PermutationImportance' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'`. Is this because I fit using `RFECV`? what I'm doing is similar to the last snippet here: https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blackbox/permutation_importance.html
3. as a less important issue, this gives me a warning when I set `cv` in `eli5.sklearn.PermutationImportance` :

*`.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:68: FutureWarning: Pass classifier=False as keyword args. From version 0.25 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error warnings.warn("Pass {} as keyword args. From version 0.25 "`*

The whole process is a bit vague. **Is there a way to do it directly in `Sklearn`?** e.g. by adding a `feature_importances` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the objective is to select the optimal number of features with permutation importance and recursive feature elimination, I suggest using `RFECV` and `PermutationImportance` in conjunction with a CV splitter like `KFold`. The code could then look like this:

```
import warnings
from eli5 import show_weights
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.svm import SVR


warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

splitter = KFold(n_splits=3) # 3 folds as in the example

estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFECV(
    PermutationImportance(estimator,  scoring='r2', n_iter=10, random_state=42, cv=splitter),
    cv=splitter,
    scoring='r2',
    step=1
)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
selector.ranking_

show_weights(selector.estimator_)
```

Regarding your issues:

1. `PermutationImportance` will calculate the feature importance and `RFECV` the r2 scoring with the same strategy according to the splits provided by `KFold`.
2. You called `show_weights` on the unfitted `PermutationImportance` object. That is why you got an error. You should access the fitted object with the `estimator_` attribute instead.
3. Can be ignored.

Comment: Okay, I see. In this case, sticking with `RFECV` is the cleaner approach in my opinion. I would then suggest providing a CV splitter object to both `RFECV` and `PermutationImportance` to make sure all metrics are calculated on the same splits. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks! that's exactly the part I'm not sure about. I thought each fold of the `RFECV` is split into smaller k folds when using `cv=k` for `PermutationImportance` in and then feature importance is calculated on the fold train and test data. Is it not the case?

Comment: From my understanding, the answer is yes and no. `RFECV` works essentially in two steps: first it determines the optimal number of features by fitting across the train folds and choosing the number of features that give the least averaged error across all folds. In this step, you are right: `PermutationImportance` will use smaller folds to compute its values. But after that, a conventional `RFE` model with the previously found optimal number of features is fit on the whole dataset to find the actual features. Now, `PermutationImportance` will use the same splits as in the step before.

Comment: This is what I understood from looking into the source code. I do not see a way to ensure the splits are also the same in the first step. This is probably the best compromise you can get unless you define your own method. But you definitely want cross-validation also for `PermutationImportance`. Because otherwise, the feature importance is calculated on the data the estimator was trained on and thus, does not reflect importance of features for generalization.

Comment: There's any alternative to avoid this split-in-split situation ? Because now it takes prohibitive amount of time

Answer (score 1):

You can directly compute RFECV using sklearn by building your estimator that computes feature importance, using any logic you want, when calling fit.

If you want to compute feature importance based on permutation using an SVR regressor, the estimator you have to implement is:

```
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVR

class SVRExplainerRegressor(SVR):
    def fit(self, X,y):
        X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
            X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42, shuffle=True
        )
        super().fit(X_train,y_train)
        
        self.perm_feature_importances_ = permutation_importance(
            self, X_val, y_val, 
            n_repeats=5, random_state=42,
        )['importances_mean']
        
        return super().fit(X,y)
```

`SVRExplainerRegressor` does the following:

- split the received data into training and validation
- training is used to fit an SVR regressor
- validation is used to compute and store the feature importances using the permutation technique
- in the end, a final training is computed using all the data received

`SVRExplainerRegressor` can be used like any sklearn model as RFECV's estimator in this way:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

model = SVRExplainerRegressor(kernel='linear')
selector = RFECV(model, step=1, min_features_to_select=1, 
                 importance_getter='perm_feature_importances_', 
                 scoring='r2', cv=3)
selector.fit(X, y)
```

This logic can be customized using any estimator (both regressor or classifier)  and any feature importance logic (like SHAP or similar)